# Error: Invalid hook call in Apollo useLazyQuery , useMutation, useQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, apollo-client

As long as the line with `useLazyQuery` in `App.js` (code below) is removed, it will display simple "HELLO" message (working well), otherwise, I got the below error message

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { syncUser as syncRecord } from "./components/util";
import { useLazyQuery } from "@apollo/client";

export default function App(props) {
  console.log("React.version1", React.version);
  console.log("ReactDOM.version1", ReactDOM.version);
  const [syncUser] = useLazyQuery(syncRecord, {}); //CULPRIT LINE
  const [hasToken, setHasToken] = React.useState(false);
  return <div className="App">HELLO</div>;
}
```

A few things I have checked

1. React version & React DOM version are same in index.js & App.js i.e. `16.13.1`
2. I don't think I broke Hooks rule -- `useState` working well in the same sample code `App.js`
3. `npm ls react` returns long tree with multiple react (but other than react at root tree -- the rest (part of the library) are using same react@16.3.1 deduped

Apollo Client version

```
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.15",
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
```

The base project is node js server-side code, and I created a `client` directory in it - which contains also a React app.

client package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4567/",
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

server-side package.json

```
{
  "name": "cmis",
  "version": "0.3.0",
  "description": "NodeJS",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build",
    "test": "node test.js",
    "generate": "plop",
    "client": "cd client && yarn start",
    "server": "nodemon -e js,graphql server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.15",
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-codebuild": "^3.20.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.20.0",
    "@david.kucsai/react-pdf-table": "^0.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^1.6.12",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.0",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.804.0",
    "bull": "^3.19.1",
    "constant-case": "^3.0.4",
    "dataloader": "^2.0.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.9.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^2.5.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.11.0",
    "express-jwt": "^6.0.0",
    "express-jwt-authz": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "filepond": "^4.23.1",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-size": "^2.2.2",
    "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation": "^1.0.9",
    "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^4.6.4",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^6.2.1",
    "jwks-rsa": "^1.11.0",
    "knex": "^0.21.5",
    "pg": "^8.3.3",
    "pluralize": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.5",
    "react-filepond": "^7.1.0",
    "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.9",
    "react-typist": "^2.0.5",
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "swiper": "^6.5.3",
    "throng": "^5.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^6.0.0-alpha.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
    "got": "^11.3.0",
    "plop": "^3.0.5",
    "tape": "^4.7.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "heroku",
    "express"
  ],
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Comment: do you happen to have a git repo inside another git repo? Meaning you have two node_modules folder.. that can cause same issue.

Comment: yes I have two node_modules (for server & client side app) , but both of them are part 1 git repo

Comment: that could be the reason - two installations of react. It may not appear in your server side package.json but it could be one of the dependencies installed, causing the error. You may want to separate the packages or combine them into one. You may want to share your detail set up for better advise

Comment: thank you @SomeoneSpecial . I added more detail to the question itself...

Comment: can you split your client and server into two folders? If you need to continue with this set up, then maintain only one package.json, and use webpack to manage which folder to be compile for the client. Are you using SSR? It seems all your packages are in your server side package.json.. then why have a client side package.json?

Comment: I am not using server-side rendering -- only pure create-react-app for the client side. I put in 1 project so that I could have a code generator that updates both client and server-side code at once. Am I right to say that I should put `server` folder and `client` folder at the same level so that the `package.json` will not interfere each other -- and then put both folders in the `root` of the project? I don't know exactly why the library was ended up mostly at server side (package.json)... btw this setup work well for few months, until i upgraded to latest node version

Comment: You are right about using only one package.json. Or put them in separate folders, each with their package.json

Comment: Thank you @SomeoneSpecial. You're indeed special. How could I accept the above answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your node_modules folder(also from the recycle bin)

and run `npm install`

It worked for me because i had two node_modules folder in the project directory

Comment: Thanks, @Jineesh for your suggestion. I tried  (delete node_modules and run `npm install`) - and it upgraded my react version to 17.0.2 -- but the issue remains

Comment: This solution finally work - in addition to that, I need to clean up the mess in package.json (at client folder)

Comment: Hi @iwan how did you clean the package.json ?